# Query in google sheets with date reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having an issue regarding my Query function in Google Sheets where I will reference a cell with a date in order for me to filter the data from a specific column with specific conditions.

I am expecting the query to return a list of customers from the database by date range.
Here's an overview.

The Dataset:

Name           State       Date         Order  Qty
April Smith IL  11/1/2023   Apple   3
Jane Doe    IL  11/3/2023   Orange  1
James Smith GA  11/9/2023   Apple   5
Jessica Roberts IL  11/10/2023  Apple   3
Mary Kaye   IL  11/17/2023  Orange  1
Christine May   GA  11/20/2023  Apple   5

This is how should it works

Start Date  11/1/2023   End Date    11/9/2023

Name
April Smith
Jane Doe
James Smith

So far, I tried the filter method and I also tried this one:

=QUERY('database'!B5:Y,"Select A where
A is not null
and C => date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
and C =< date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'
",1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with incorrect operators. Use `>=` and `<=`, like this:

```
=query( 
  'database'!A5:Y, 
  "select A 
   where A is not null 
   and C >= date " & text(B1, "'yyyy-MM-dd'") & " 
   and C <= date " & text(D1, "'yyyy-MM-dd'"), 
  1 
)
```

Alternatively, use `filter()` and `isbetween()`:

`=filter('database'!A6:A, isbetween('database'!C6:C, B1, D1))`